# Can I filter my Steam library by tags or features?

Tags: steam

I can look through the "Store" portion of Steam using tags, and I can also do an advanced-search on certain features like local co-op support.  But for some reason, when I do this I can't tell which games I already own, and I don't seem to be able to do the same search / filter when viewing my library.

Am I missing an option somewhere?  It seems like a no-brainer to be allowed to do this.

Comment: I can't comment, yet, so I had to leave an answer. The "Library" feature for Enhanced Steam is only available for the Chrome version. - http://www.enhancedsteam.com/blog/chrome-version-3-7-1-released-new-beta-library-feature/

Answer (score 119):

Some months ago I made **[a tool](http://www.lorenzostanco.com/lab/steam/)** for this exact purpose.
You can filter your library or wishlist by any combination of one or more tags and features, and also sort by your playtime or Metascore. You're welcome :)

> http://www.lorenzostanco.com/lab/steam/

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I wanted. I really hope Steam adds filtering in to the library at some point, but until then this is amazing!

Comment: I used your tool to find all local co-op/multiplayer games I own and put them in a separate category. It's currently not possible to filter on features/tags in Steam, but it is possible to filter on category in Big Picture mode. Thanks for creating this.

Comment: @lorenzo-s This is great! I was looking for a way to filter 4p local coop for an upcoming LAN and this tool worked perfectly.

Comment: Very nice tool, grazie @lorenzo-s

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't seem to work for libraries with a high number of games (~2000 games). It spits all of them on the page, so it gets really slow and for each game it says it couldn't get game info. :(

Comment: @FilipVondrášek Thank you for reporting, the *cannot get game info* error was caused by an accidental empty update occurred today, I just fixed it. I've tested with 7k+ libraries with no problems (ok, some slowdown, actually), and I'm aware of a lot of people with huge libraries using it.

Comment: Thank you, @lorenzo-s. Thank you very much for the website, I highly appreciate it. Sometimes I even want to buy a game, only to realize I already have it, so it is very useful for me. :) thanks!

Comment: Any chance you can add filtering by ESRB rating? I'm not sure what I should let my son try out of my Humble Bundle games, and that rating is a nice place to start, at least. To be fair, I know it's not always accurate, which is why I will still look at them.

Comment: @JoshuaNurczyk Unfortunately Steam does not provide ESRB rating for games. Some games have an ESRB badge on the store right column, other have PEGI, but it'is always completely optional, and very rare to see :(

Comment: @lorenzo-s Over half of mine that I looked at had them. I don't dispute that they're rare overall, though. I guess I just have to play each one a bit before exposing him to them. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 10):

You can filter games in your library using certain features by using [Enhanced Steam](http://www.enhancedsteam.com/) (browser plugin for FF and Chrome). You'll need to install the plugin to your browser, go to Steam website and enter the settings from the new Enhanced Steam dropdown. Then enable Library (BETA, only available in Chrome), if it's not already enabled and go back to Steam's website. You should see a link to your library at the top of the page. Click it and you can easily filter your library:

[image: STEAM LIBRARY - Categories... Genres...]

Categories include the features you can see on the right on Store pages such as VR-support, local co-op, multiplayer and controller support. Genres include, well, genres.

**The best way to search for games with tags** is by going to the tag page (`http://store.steampowered.com/tag/<language>/<tag>/` where language is the shortcode for a country such as "en" for English or "fi" for Finnish) and browsing for games you own (Enhanced Steam can help you highlight those as well). You can further filter those results by using the filters on the right.

Comment: I just tried, but I don't see any way to see a "library", entering the options from the add on windows, doesn't show anything either. Same with the official webpage that doesn't state anything about the library. I'm confused :/

Comment: It is a beta feature, you have to enable it in the Options of ES.

Comment: @Sentry there don't seem to be any mention of the "library" in the addon options.

Comment: @zespri There is, directly in the first menu: `Store -> Library (BETA) -> Show Library button in header`. See also: http://www.enhancedsteam.com/blog/chrome-version-3-7-1-released-new-beta-library-feature/

Comment: @Sentry lol, that's chrome version. The answer says FF. There is NO Library for FF, so that's wrong. No wonder people are confused. Anyway mystery solved. Thanks. PS. - Edited the answer to clarify that part, hopefully it get reviewed soon.

Comment: That's why missing library: - Removed library functionality due to API changes made by Valve (changelog, from version 7.2)

Answer (score 3):

Since the "Discovery" update a few days ago, the Steam store now marks games that are in your library on various search and store pages.

Here's me searching for the co-op and fps tags:
[image: Steam Discovery search page]

The ones that are dimmed and have the 3 bar icon are games I already own.

Note: I'm using common tags to demonstrate how it works, you can search by less common tags using the search box.

However, the library itself has **not** been changed to search by tag.

Comment: Thank you for postings this but it only helps a little - you can't really be sure that items you own come on the top and you can't filter by ownership. In your case you were lucky that the sort by relevance brings on top items that you have, unfortunately that's not the case for me.

Comment: With the new update, what's the way of searching for games not `NON RPG` games for example ?

Answer (score 2):

[This tool](http://steam.tools/games/) lets you filter your games by Singleplayer, Multiplayer, Co-op, Local co-op, Controller, Mac, and/or Linux. It can also let you filter an intersection of games between different accounts.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to filter the Steam Library by Steam Community tags or feature lists.

You can, however, apply a single category to every game through the context menu of the item in the library. Your games then get grouped by category.

Comment: That said, as for "which games I already own", I would recommend the [Enhanced Steam](http://www.enhancedsteam.com/) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I found a tool that requires a little more work than the web-based ones above, but has an amazing amount of functionality.  [Depressurizer](https://github.com/rallion/depressurizer) will parse your Steam library and load it into the application for query and edit.  You can sort / filter games by categories, tags, all sorts of stuff.  You can automatically apply bulk label operations based on certain conditions, etc, then sync your changes back to your library.

If you just want simple search, use one of the web-based ones in the other high-ranked answers.  If you want powerful tag/category *modification* tools then definitely try Depressurizer.

Comment: Works fantastic for modifying categories. Took five minutes to set up some auto-categorization filters and categorize 1000+ games. However, the linked repo in the answer is no longer maintained. Try [this one](https://github.com/mvegter/Depressurizer) instead.

Answer (score -1):

Shameless plug, you can use my site to filter your **single-player** games by genre, metacritic score, and release year: https://www.howlongtobeatsteam.com.

Just go to the table at the bottom and click "Advanced Filter". You can then sort the results by playtime if you're so inclined.

Answer (score -2):

You can set a category for each game yourself and it will alter the dropdowns by category; to do so, you have to do the following:

1. Right click on the game you want to categorize.
2. Select Set Category...
3. Type the name of the category you'd like to make and select add category.
4. Then select OK

This only works on a one at a time basis (have to give a category to each game individually), however if you create a category you can select it again without having to re-create it. Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Comment: This is not answer on acctual problem.