# Can I search my Steam library titles and sort them by user review?

Tags: steam

I, like many other Steam users, own quite a few games, and have trouble ever deciding which ones to try next. My favorite metric these days is the user review scores, but I can find no way to apply this to my library.

I did find this question: [Can I filter my Steam library by tags or features?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159350/can-i-filter-my-steam-library-by-tags-or-features)
However, the accepted answer is from back in April (before the discovery update) and the additional answer added in September doesn't address all the possibilities I am looking for insight on.

I have dug around and can find no indication of being able to search by anything other than the available columns in list view (name, metascore, last played etc.) However, I know that the core search now shows which titles are in your library. Is it possible to use the general search and filter by only the titles in your library? (The answer to this according to the Sep. answer on the aforementioned question is No)

Is there anyone who has come up with some sly way of helping filter down lists to a close approximation of your owned games. If so, then I could leverage the additional useful sortations found in general search (user review and release date for sure) also having the ability to filter on things like number of players, features and everyone else's tags.

I have tried various tricks to get the search to filter in unpublicized ways, is there a super-user out there that has cracked this nut or is it truly not possible at this point?

Comment: @aytimothy To clarify: the intent of my question may be mired in sortation/organization, but it is meant to be squarely aimed at finding a way to use "user reviews" for my owned library to decide which one of my titles I should play next. The rest of the sort/org debacle is secondary and the question you mentioned does address many of those concerns. (I partially did not reference it because I wanted to distance this question from general ones about org/sort)...something I appear to have failed at anyway.

Comment: I know that but... The thing is: It's not possible. The Steam API does not allow anyone to retrieve game rating data. **Read the big bold header** please.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a duplicate; the other question has nothing about sorting by user reviews.

Comment: You can do this by using https://steamdb.info/calculator/ (this question is marked as duplicate, so I can't add an answer, while I don't believe it is duplicate)

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, you can. But only for Metacritic scores.

*You can only sort through user reviews **in the store**.*

As @Ross Ridge said:

> As mentioned by the original poster, you can sort your games by Metacritic metascore by using the Steam client. Switch the Library to the List View and click on the the metascore column header. – Ross Ridge
> [Can I search my Steam library titles and sort them by user review?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190225/can-i-search-my-steam-library-titles-and-sort-them-by-user-review/190227?noredirect=1#comment257806_190227)

---

There are tools out there like [Depressurizer](https://github.com/rallion/depressurizer/releases), but it only allows you to sort through your games using categories...

As per current, the Steam API does not allow anyone to retrieve review ratings/metacritic scores (without using the Metacritic API) for a game. But metacritic scores are included in the Steam client anyway... So:

#### No, you cannot sort by user reviews in your library. Only in the store.

It should be possible, if you check the store page and look for what's in the following `<DIV>` tags:
`es_review_tags`, though to point out that both the upvote and the downvote uses the same CSS class.

Comment: As mentioned by the original poster, you can sort your games by Metacritic metascore by using the Steam client. Switch the Library to the List View and click on the the metascore column header.

Comment: You can only sort them in the store. Not your library.

Comment: You're mistaken.  Follow the instructions I gave and see.

Comment: I completely forgot about that.

Comment: As I said, the original poster already mentioned that you can do this. It's not the answer to his question.

Comment: I quote myself: "As per current, the Steam API does not allow anyone to retrieve review ratings/metacritic scores (without using the Metacritic API) for a game. But metacritic scores are included in the Steam client anyway... So: No, you cannot sort by user reviews in your library. Only in the store."