# How can I find the non-family games in my Steam library?

Tags: steam

I have a number of games in my *Steam* library. Not all of them are family games, which means they don't show up when using the family view.
I can manually add games to the family games, so my kids can play them without needing me to log in for them.

When *not* in familiy view, I can filter my library by family games (it's the option right below *Favourites*), but I would like to filter by non-family games, to see if there are any I should reclassify so my kids can play them.

**How do I find the non-family games in my *Steam* library?**

I *thought* the games got their classification by their publishers, but it may very well be possible that all games start out as non-family. Regardless, I'd like to see the ones that aren't family games yet.

---

*Note that I'm **not** asking about family sharing, but about the family friendliness ratings the games get.*

Answer (score 4):

Are you already using manually set categories? This might be useful in combination with what you're already doing.

One can manually create new categories for their Steam games, and then manually flag their games as going into that category.

To start, right click on a title and select, "Set Categories..." on the popup menu. In the middle of the next popup, there's a field sitting next to a button labeled "Add Category". Create one called "Non-Family Games". A checked checkbox should appear in the list above the field.

Go into "Set Categories..." for other titles, and click the checkbox for your new category. Repeat for other titles.

Now you should have a new option to filter your games by "Non-Family Games".

Comment: That would work, but that would require me to already have done this. But the problem itself is finding the non-family games. Right now, the only option is going through all of my games, then right-click to see if they're already added.

Answer (score 2):

There is a related question here, and one of the answers there will probably scratch your itch:

[Can I filter my Steam library by tags or features?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159350/can-i-filter-my-steam-library-by-tags-or-features)

To summarize:

1. Use http://www.lorenzostanco.com/lab/steam/ to filter your library. Once you've fed the URL for your profile into the site, you can filter your library by any tag, or **by the inverse of any tag**. I just tried this myself: Clicking once on a tag will filter to show only games matching the tag. Clicking on the same tag again will filter to show only games NOT matching the tag.

OR

2. Use Enhanced Steam (www.enhancedsteam.com) which is Chrome and Firefox supported. Then browse store.steampowered.com, it will also give you an "exclude by tag" option. But with this approach, you'll be looking at ALL of Steam's games, not just the ones you own. I have yet to figure out how to tell Enhanced Steam to show only games that I own.