# Can I search my Steam library for absence of a tag?

Tags: steam

I've already asked [how to find the non-family games in my *Steam* library](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/295677/75191). How do I do the same with the pre-set or manually added categories?
For instance, about half of the games in my library are simulators of a kind. Every once in a while, I'd like to play a non-simulator game.

**How do I search or filter for *absence* of a tag?**

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is, disappointingly, only available in Steam's Big Picture mode.  The filtering, there, is more enhanced, and can work as an answer to your previous question, in addition to this one.

If you activate Big Picture mode (click the game controller at the top-right), then you can go into Library, then click Games, and click Filter Games, on the right side of the page.  With this, you can setup more complex filtering than you can in the normal client.  Personally, I hope they add these features into the normal client, soon.

You can see an example, from mine, here.
[image]

Since there's no real way to search for the *absence* of a tag, you'd have to select all of the tags that you want, and leave out that tag.  If there's a more convenient way to do this, from within Steam, I'm unaware of it, yet.